# set default values if empty

Tags: jquery

I'm changing the text of an element based on the input:

```
$("input#txtName").keyup(function(){
      $(".website-info h3 strong").text($(this).val());
    });
$("input#txtUrl").keyup(function(){
      $(".website-info h3 small").text($(this).val());
    });
```

It works, but I want to show default values as soon as the text is empty or user has entered nothing to prevent white space. I tried the `if... is.(:empty)` condition but it doesn't help cause `.text` doesn't seem to set default values.

Comment: `$(this).val().length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A concise and pretty standard way of doing this is using the `||` operator.

```
$("input#txtName").keyup(function(){
      $(".website-info h3 strong").text($(this).val() || "Default text");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `placeholder` HTML attribute of input elements. Set the attribute in your HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="default text here" />
```

or with jQuery after the page loads

```
$("input#txtName").attr("placeholder", "default text here");
```

Here is [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input) on the `<input>` element

Answer (score 0):

Change both of your text assignments to a variant of the following:

`$(".website-info h3 small").text(($(this).val().length) ? $(this).val() : "Your default value here");`

Be warned that this will not throw the default value if the user enters a whitespace - if you'd like to do this, you'll need to edit the ternary operator accordingly.